# Rsyslog segregate logs for wildcard files

Tags: logging, error-logging, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I have a central server to log my different application logs, i forward the logs using rsyslog's(8.36) wildcard(`/var/log/sample/*.log`), i'd like to segregate the logs on my central server based upon the filename being monitored, how do i go about it?

Forwarder:

```
`input(type="imfile" File="/var/log/sample/*.log"
Tag="sample-req_params.log"
StateFile="/var/spool/rsyslog/app-req_params"
Severity="error"
Facility="local7")
*.* @@X.XX.X.XXX:514`
```

Receiver:

```
`$template MYFILENAME,"/var/log/sample/%programname%.log"
if $programname contains 'sample' then ?MYFILENAME`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for this not being the greatest answer, but I hope I can push you into the right direction. The default templates do not transmit the file name. On the original system, however, it is available as [imfile metadata](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/imfile.html?highlight=imfile%20metadata#metadata). You need to define a template on the client side that contains that metadata and the use it on the server side to extract the file name.